# How can I play audio with playsound and type in an entry box at the same time in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, playsound

I want to type something in the `user_text` entry box while the `play_audio` function is running

I tried the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from playsound import playsound

root = Tk()


def play_audio():
    playsound('audio.mp3')


play_audio_button = Button(root, text='Play audio', command=play_audio)
user_text = Entry(root)

play_audio_button.pack()
user_text.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

mainloop()
```

but it doesn't let me do anything while the audio is playing in the background. It only lets me type after the audio is finished.

I also tried doing the same thing withouth tkinter and it works:

```
def play_audio():
    playsound('audio.mp3')


play_audio()
play_audio_input = input('Your text: \n')
```

It does let me type while the audio is playing in the background that way.

So how can I get it to work in tkinter?

Answer (score 1):

`playsound` can run sound in the background if you set `block=False`, you should use threads if you need to loop the sound or something more than just running a single sound file.

```py
def play_audio():
    playsound('audio.mp3', block=False)
```

if you want to loop the sound you don't need multiprocessing, the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module is perfectly usable for running tasks in the background, which will run the audio in another thread, leaving the main thread to run your GUI.

```py
import threading

def play_audio():
    while True:
        playsound('audio.mp3')

play_audio_button = Button(root, text='Play audio', command=lambda: threading.Thread(play_audio).start())
```

Comment: So why does it work for OP in pure Python with playing in the background but blocks the current thread execution (tkinter main loop) when using tkinter?

Comment: @xuiqzy in that case the terminal does the rendering and input handling not python. python just doesn't process the typed input until it is done playing the sound, unlike when python has to render the GUI, and handle inputs to the GUI, a blocking `playsound` function makes the entire GUI hang

Comment: Ah thanks. So if OP tried to print the entered text directly after the `input()` it would not work until the audio is finished playing. Or it would not work at all with text entered *while* the audio is playing because the entered text was not fed to the `input()` function when typing while the audio is playing, correct?

Comment: @xuiqzy yes, it won't work until the audio finishes playing. a blocking function means python is stuck in a loop sleeping while playing the sound and doesn't reach the `input` until it is done playing the sound. you can still interact with the terminal and put text in it and press enter, that will just have the terminal put the text in a buffer for python to read later when it reaches the `input` function.

Comment: OK thanks, I got the blocking part, I was just wondering if the terminal buffers it for python or if it is just ignored by the terminal because nobody is reading stdin, but that answers that.